# Latex, karnaugh-map usepackage, unable to connect specific cells

Tags: latex, diagram, karnaugh-map

I need to use the \usepackage{karnaugh-map} to draw some karnaugh-map. In this table:

```
\begin{karnaugh-map}

    \manualterms{1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1}

\end{karnaugh-map}
```

I would like to operate the logical connection like in the photo
[image]

But I really don't know how to operate the link between 0 and 8, and also between 3 and 11. Is there anyway to obtain something like in the picture

Comment: The red lines {0, 3, 8, 11} actually do not mark a valid block. You are not allowed to join cells, unless they just differ in terms of one input. {0, 8} and {3,11} would be valid pairs, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might come close:

```
\begin{karnaugh-map}
   \manualterms{1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1}
   \implicant{13}{11}
   \implicant{15}{10}
   \implicantedge{0}{0}{8}{8}
   \implicantedge{3}{3}{11}{11}
\end{karnaugh-map}
```

[image]

You can find more information in the manual [karnaugh-map.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/karnaugh-map/karnaugh-map.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

It seemed very abstract but all that i needed for my case was understanding how the map is labeled. It is labeled as a k map itsealf,
|col1|col2 | col3| col4|
|--|---|---|---|
| 0|  1|  3|  2|
| 4|  5|  7|  6|
|12| 13| 15| 14|
| 8|  9| 11| 10|

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 | 7 | 6 |
| 12 | 13 | 15 | 14 |
| 8 | 9 | 11 | 10 |

skip the 3 element and fill later
Following these indices its easier to plot the kmap using the kanaugh-map package